# How do I mount the boot partition from Macos?

Tags: boot, ssh, partition

When I attempt to find this partition (on Macos), here's what it's showing me:

```
/dev/disk3 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.8 GB    disk3
   1:             Windows_FAT_16 RECOVERY                1.5 GB     disk3s1
   2:                      Linux                         33.6 MB    disk3s5
```

It looks as if s2-s4 are invisible. Is this where the boot partition is? It does not seem to be s1.

I just need to touch ssh on this so I can get a shell... I don't have a monitor/keyboard to do that with, and I don't have a linux machine which might make this easier.

Comment: Trying on my iMac. Edited it to include that. I'm trying to mount the boot partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you did NOT use NOOBS , the boot partition is the only partition that MacOS can access and display. It will be automatically visible. Just create an empty file named "ssh" there and SSH will be enabled on the next boot of a Pi from this card.

By the way , there are 2 types of partitions : Primary and extended. 30 years ago , you could only have 4 primary partitions. Somebody invented extended partitions , which are implemented as special primary partition record. That is why extended partitions start at 5 on unixoid systems.